# Microsoft Dynamics GP disconnects after intro of Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

A site has had 10-15 laptops running GP wirelessly for years.  The first Windows 10 laptop introduced into production, is freezing up in GP due to disconnects (so says GP support).  Power management has already been delved into and set for maximum connectivity, even though this was not necessary for the other clients.  Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Have you tried a wired connection on the affected machine?

Comment: Should have thought of that!  Doing it.

Comment: No change while working wired!  I am quite surprised.  This is Dynamics GP 2015, version 14.00.1012.000.